# Creating a table in UNIX using tbl & troff

Tags: unix, troff

I have to create a table in troff, what I have:

```
.TS
tab(:);
c s s
c | c | c
l | l | n.
My Custome PC Specs
=
Component:Selection:Price
_
CPU:Intel Core i5-4690K 3.5GHz Quad-Core Processor:$219.99  
_
Motherboard:MSI Z97-GAMING 5 ATX LGA1150:$129.88
_
Memory:Corsair Vengeance Pro 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3-1866 Memory:$74.88 
_
Storage:Sandisk X110 128GB 2.5" Solid State Drive:FREE  
\^:Western Digital 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive:$38.77  
_
Video Card:MSI GeForce GTX 970 4GD5T OC 4GB GDDR5:$289.99   
_
Case:Corsair Graphite Series 230T Orange ATX Mid Tower Case:$73.46
_
Power Supply:CorsairCX 750W 80+ Bronze Certified Semi-Modular ATX:$59.99
_
Optical Drive:Asus DRW-24B1ST/BLK/B/AS DVD/CD Writer:$12.89 
_
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro OEM (64-bit):FREE
_
WAN: TP-Link TL-WN881ND 802.11b/g/n PCI-Express Wi-Fi Adapter:$18.89
_
Case Fan: Cooler Master SickleFlow 69.7 CFM 120mm Fan:$9.99
_
Monitor:Monoprice 12178 144Hz 24.0" Monitor:$229.99
_
Keyboard: Corsair Vengeance K70 Wired Gaming Keyboard:$119.99
_
Mouse: Razer DeathAdder 2013 Wired Optical Mouse:$59.99
_
Total: :$1,388.70
_
.TE
```

I try to execute by typing  `tbl [filename] | troff`, but I am not getting the 
table, I've tried using other options but I'm not sure if I understand how troff works.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used `troff` etc. I don't recall lines with only `_`. Is that part of `tbl`? If I have messed up your data, you can click on the `edited .. ago` link above my name and "roll-back" my change. But I would recommend that you `edit` your post, delete the `tbl` data, paste it in fresh and use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box to keep the proper formatting as code/data/etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

With *GNU Troff*, I have successfully processed your file using the following invocation:

```
groff -t -Tascii tbl.tr > tbl.txt
```

`-t` tells `troff` to use run the `tbl` preprocessor and `-Tascii` set the `ascii` output device, which produces plain text output.

Here are the first three lines of the result:

```
                                    My Custome PC Specs
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------
   Component     |                         Selection                         |    Price
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------
CPU              | Intel Core i5-4690K 3.5GHz Quad-Core Processor            |   $219.99
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------
Motherboard      | MSI Z97-GAMING 5 ATX LGA1150                              |   $129.88
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------
```

Your error came from ignorance of *troff* options.  Please, peruse the corresponding section of the manual either for [*GNU Troff*](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Groff-Options.html#Groff-Options) or for whatever other flavour you may be using.

The best source of help with GNU Troff is its [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/groff/).